# Is it safe to kill a thread that is executing a memcpy?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, terminate, memory-mapped-files

**Context:**

I am working on an application that needs fast access to large files, so I use memory-mapping. Reading and writing becomes a simple `memcpy` in consequence. I am now trying to add the ability to abort any reads or writes in progress.

The first thing that came to mind (since I don't know about any interruptable memcpy function) was to periodically `memcpy` a few KB and check if the operation should be aborted. This should ensure a near-instantanious abortion, if the read is reasonably fast.

If it isn't however the application shouldn't take ages to abort, so my second idea was using multithreading. The memcpy happens in its own thread, and a controlling thread uses `WaitForMultipleObjects` on an event that signals abortion, and the memcpy-thread. It would then kill the memcpy-thread, if the abortion-event was signaled. However, the [documentation on TerminateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) states that one should be absolutely sure that one does not leave the system in a bad state by not releasing ressource for instance.

**Question:**

Does a memcpy do anything that would make it unsafe to kill it when copying mapped memory? Is it safe to do so? Is it implementation dependant (using different operating systems/architectures than Windows x86-64)?

---

I do realize that using the second approach may be complete overkill, since no 1KB read/write is every going to take that long realistically, but I just want to be safe.

Comment: There is a school of thought saying you shouldn't terminate threads.

Comment: Consider doing that `memcpy` in chunks of reasonable size (e.g. a megabyte) whose copy would *typically* last a few milliseconds. You could test after that copy some atomic flag, or protect that copy with a mutex, etc... and loop around that.

Comment: This guy knows (much) more than me _"There are still people who think that there are valid scenarios for calling Terminate­Thread."_: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811

Comment: ok, so i guess the moral of the story is: "memcpy doesn't matter, TerminateThread is just a horrible idea"? Polling it is then!

Comment: if you will use ReadFile/WriteFile instead with asynchronous file handle you can break/cancel read/write operation at any time

Comment: It's never safe to kill a thread ever

Comment: That's an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What you really want is interruptable I/O. Asynchronous [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) allows you to call [CanelIo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363791.aspx) at any time. Memory-mapped files do not buy you much (if anything) in terms of speed anyway, so you can drop that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If at all possible you should choose a different design, `TerminateThread` should not be thought of as a normal function, it is more for debugging/power tools.

I would recommend that you create a wrapper around `memcpy` that copies in chunks. The chunk size is really up to you, depends on your responsiveness requirements. 1 MiB is probably a good starting point.

If you absolutely want to kill threads you have to take a couple of things into account:

- You obviously don't know anything about how `memcpy` works internally nor how much it copied so you have to assume that the whole range is undefined when you abort.
- Terminating a thread will leak memory on some versions of Windows. There are [workarounds](http://www.nicklowe.org/2012/01/thread-termination-dont-leak-the-stack/) for that.
- Don't hold any locks in the thread.